# WCF service big Linq response

Tags: c#, wcf, linq

I'm using WCF to return a list of complex objects returned from SQL Server with Linq.

I want to return a list of objects with around 16 properties and 2 References to other complex types (with around 8 properties each one).

I've seen in fiddler that each object returned (when serialized to XML) is around 5KB and, when I try to return a full list (900 items) it's around 3MB!!!

Is this normal? Is there any other way to serialize data to a light-weight format?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: There are any number of ways to serialize data, e.g. CSV, JSON, but it depends on what you need to provide to your service consumer?  Can you reduce the size of the list your produce?  900 records seems a lot.

Comment: Yes, I think that I can add pages to the result, but I need to load a full datagrid in just one page 8-)

Comment: Well it may just be me, but I can think of few times where working with a 100+ row grid all in one go is a great idea...

Comment: Its not just you, the size of 3mb for 900 items seems appropriate

Comment: That's not my idea, it's just client requirement :'(

Comment: This might not sound very useful, but in these cases, the client often doesn't know what they want.  They may not have considered paging etc., and may be happy to get a different/more performant mechanism.

Comment: I agree with Paddy. Also, if they insist on having all 900items in one big step, they have to live with it taking some time. Its not like you can do anything in any time desireable. Thats not how this computerthing works unfortunatly :-( At least you have enough arguments now to get into further discussion with your client and present alternatives.

Comment: You are right ;-) I'll try it again with a paging version vs their "requirement" version and time will tell. Thank you all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into [NetTcpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.nettcpbinding.aspx) if this is possible for you, this will reduce network traffic very much compared to XML Serialization

Comment: Will NetTcpBinding let me use this services as usual?? (I mean that the client-side should create a copy of all classes...)

Comment: @zapico: changing the binding to Net TCP should have no effect on the service. You should just be able to change both the server's and client's config files to use this binding, and it will all just work! You don't need to re-reference the service or re-generate any proxy classes.

Answer (score 3):

XML is very verbose, and that size does not really surprise me (taking the size of your list into consideration - 900 items is too much, if you ask me).

If you need to "pack" your data, i'd recommend serializing your objects to JSON, since that removes a lot of verbosity. There is a built-in [JSON Serialization mechanism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179.aspx), so you should be able to get started really fast. The only thing i had problems with, were the DateTime fields, which sometimes error'd with the built-in JSON Serializer, but there are workarounds to that.

However that will also mean some work would have to be done on both ends. Serverside, you need to transform your entities to some kind of transport entities, or [DTO](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html)s, if you will. On client side, you cant work with those right away, but need to deserialize the data first, and re-built your datamodel from there.

You'd want to pack in a "DTO Info" in your sent object, so your client knows what to expect of the packets it is receiving. Like, which type has been serialized, and so on.